# How to process partial payment in Point Of Sale in Odoo10?

Tags: point-of-sale, odoo-10

**Is there any configuration using that we can process partial payment of Point Of Sale - Odoo10..?**

Comment: No, but  you can purchase this module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/pos_partial_pay/